# SQL - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, innodb, sqlfiddle

I am completely new to writing SQL code and I am attempting to run a simple table creation, however I cannot find where the error in my programming is, and as I am completely new I am struggling with this creation.

This is a school project that I am working on, and hoping anyone can help.

The error I am receiving in 'SQLFiddle' is "Cannot add foreign key constraint" on the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice(
  invoice_id INT NOT NULL,
  customer_id INT NOT NULL,
  order_date DATE NULL,
  spec_order_note VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(invoice_id, customer_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
  REFERENCES customer.customer_id
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE line_item (
  invoice_id INT NOT NULL,
  donut_id INT NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NULL
  CONSTRAINT donut_invoice
  FOREIGN KEY invoice_id
  REFERENCES invoice.invoice_id
  ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)

CREATE TABLE donut (
  donut_id INT NOT NULL,
  donut_name VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  description VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  unit_price INT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY(donut_id),
)

CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id INT NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  street_add VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  apt_num INT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  state VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  zip_code INT NULL,
  home_phone VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  mobile_phone VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  other_phone VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  customer_notes VARCHAR(45) NULL
  PRIMARY KEY(customer_id),
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably create `customer` table before you try to reference it in `invoice`'s foreign key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using two foreign keys as a primary key - MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488238/using-two-foreign-keys-as-a-primary-key-mysql) - while the title suggests these are different, the cause of the problem and the solution are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only reference existing tables and columns in foreign constraints. So if you want to reference `customer` table in `invoice`'s foreign key, you need to either create `customer` before `invoice` or add the foreign key constrain additionally using `ALTER TABLE`.

Apart of that, there's couple syntax errors in your code like missing semicolons and misplaced (missing and additional) commas.

A working code:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id INT NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  street_add VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  apt_num INT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  state VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  zip_code INT NULL,
  home_phone VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  mobile_phone VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  other_phone VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  customer_notes VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE invoice(
  invoice_id INT NOT NULL,
  customer_id INT NOT NULL,
  order_date DATE NULL,
  spec_order_note VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(invoice_id, customer_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
  REFERENCES customer (customer_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE line_item (
  invoice_id INT NOT NULL,
  donut_id INT NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT donut_invoice
  FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id)
  REFERENCES invoice (invoice_id)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE donut (
  donut_id INT NOT NULL,
  donut_name VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  description VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  unit_price INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(donut_id)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36b044